# Javascript: How to get values from checkboxes that are created "dynamically"

Tags: javascript

So i am creating/rendering checkboxes dynamically depending on the records in my database.
This is currently the way for "displaying" those Checkboxes:

```
function formatBranch(branch) {
    return (
      "<p>\n" +
      "  <label>\n" +
      "  <input id=" + branch['name'] + " type=\"checkbox\" class=\"filled-in libraryCheckbox\">\n" +
      "  <span>" + branch['name'] + "</span>\n" +
      "  </label>\n" +
      "</p>"
    );
}
```

I now need to check which checboxes are checked and retrieve that/those specific checboxes as I am going to use them to filter out a search. Any ideas for how i can achieve this?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: The search is going to happen on server side or client side ?   Cause you can retrieve the data, loop over the checkboxes , before returning and answer to client

Comment: By saying “loop over checkboxes” I mean looping the data you fetched from the dB . Not the html .

Comment: @Mazki516 I am doing a fetch() call to the server that handles all the "communication" with the database, but the checkboxes are created in the client

Comment: Okay, so @Jin gave you right way .

Comment: Question is too broad. Check when and based on what event?

Comment: @charlietfl if there are too many checkboxes , he will need to create handler for each one , may not be the best way

Comment: @charlietfl when it is clicked really. I was hoping to achieve something similar as I did with my search bar. That the results are dynamically rendered depending on specific text/checkboxes etc.. That's why I need to see retrieve that/those specific checkboxes when they are clicked so I can limit the search

Comment: Yeah, there isn't a fixed number of checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all checkboxes values with pure js:

```
let chks = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++) {
  if(chks[i].type == "checkbox") {
    if (chks[i].checked) {
      // the checkbox is clicked
    } else {
      // checkbox is not clicked
    }
  }  
}
```

You can use it to build an array of filters or something like this

If you want to act on click, do something like this:

```
let chks = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++) {
  if(chks[i].type == "checkbox") {
    chks[i].addEventListener('change', function(e){
      if (e.target.checked) {
        // clicked
      } else {
        // not clicked
      }
    });
  }  
}
```